# Remove background drawable programmatically in Android

Tags: android, layout, background

I want to remove the background drawable `@drawable/bg` programmatically.
Is there a way to do that?

Currently, I have the following XML in my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget29"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 363, accepted):

Try this

```
RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.widget29);
relative.setBackgroundResource(0);
```

Check the setBackground functions in the [RelativeLayout documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)

Comment: I get this error: The method setBackgroundResource(int) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (null)

Comment: In case that doesn't work: check if you've used the background property and not android:src!

Comment: setBackgroundDrawable is now deprecated. @Suraj's answer below is better now.

Comment: api 16? is there anything for api 8?

Comment: try setBackgroundDrawable(null)

Comment: If the view is embedded in a larger layout this may harm the overall layout (faced this issue when using a `TableLayout`). Replacing `@drawable/bg` by a comparable (in terms of size) transparent drawable resolves this issue.

Comment: This will not work if your `minSdkVersion` is lower than 16. To support earlier versions, see my answer.

Comment: Use setBackgroundResource(0). as Answered by @AdamStelmaszczyk. ,

Comment: but using setBackgroundResource(0) will remove the outer layer of edit text, suppose I'm using a drawable for error display and when user is correct then it will remove the drawable along with the default outer line of edit text, i am working on api 8, any solution ?

Comment: @Maragues this is logically solution. But why after doing this memory usage doesn't decrease? (I'm using Android Studio Memory Monitor)

Comment: @VladimirKulyk that's a good question, I haven't tested myself and I don't have the answer. Quick ideas that come to my mind. Have you tried to force a GC? (you can do that from AS). Also might be due to some internal resource caching. If it's a large bitmap, try holding a reference and force a recycle after removing the background.

Comment: It's not working now at least for me.

Answer (score 78):

`setBackgroundResource(0)` is the best option. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29):

> Set the background to a given resource. The resource should refer to a
>   Drawable object or **0 to remove the background**.

It works everywhere, because it's since API 1.

`setBackground` was added much later, in API 16, so it will not work if your `minSdkVersion` is lower than 16.

Comment: Thank you, totally saved me after 4 hours of head-banging. This is very useful in case you dynamically create a toggled button (choice of 2 drawables) in an onClick event, but need a visible button to show before your toggled ones take over (because nothing will show until the click event happens, so when it does, you can use `setBackgroundResource(0)` to remove your earlier "set" button drawable).

Comment: This should be the chosen answer because it is best solution both in terms of memory management and api level support.

Answer (score 48):

This helped me remove background color, hope it helps someone.
`setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)`

Comment: Drawables can have padding, so if you remove background, you need to remove padding too.

Comment: setBackgroundResource(0) is the best option because, it removes the background completely hence, reducing overdraw.

Answer (score 7):

**Try this code:**

```
imgView.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

**also this one works:**

```
imgView.setImageResource(0);
```

**but be careful this one doesn't work:**

```
imgView.setImageResource(null);
```

Answer (score 4):

I try this code in **android 4+**:

```
view.setBackgroundDrawable(0);
```

Comment: The method setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Answer (score 3):

Best performance on this method :

```
imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.location_light_green);
```

Use this.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the excellent answers, if you want to achieve this via xml then you can add:

`android:background="@android:color/transparent`

to your view.

Answer (score 1):

This work for me:

```
yourview.setBackground(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)` to set the background as transparent, or use `setBackgroundColor(0)`. Here `Color.TRANSPARENT` is the default attribute from color class. It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have a case scenario and I tried all the answers from above, but always new image was created on top of the old one. The solution that worked for me is:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
```

Answer (score -3):

First, you have to write in XML layout:

```
android:visibility="invisible" <!--or set VISIBLE-->
```

then use this to show it using Java:

```
myimage.setVisibility(SHOW); //HIDE
```

Comment: What is it? What for?